# How can AC current be limited with reactance?

Tags: reactance, reactive-power

Since resistor dissipate electrical energy by converting it to heat, while capacitors and inductors store electrical energy I believe using reactance will waste less energy.

My source is 225 V, 50 Hz.

My load is an electrolysis process. I know that the current will be too high if 225 volts is applied. but I don't know how to limit the current. I would like to limit the current to 1 A.

I know:

XL=2πFL
XL = 2 * 3.142 * 50 * 0.80
XL = 251.36 ohms

is it possible? is my calculation correct?

Comment: You have lost me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Andyaka hi Andy I was hopping you answer, thank goodness, I want to use reactance to limit the current from the main please assist me.

Comment: What is your AC mains voltage and frequency and what is the load you want to connect? How much voltage can be allowed across the load? What minimum voltage must your load have?

Comment: @Andyaka 225v 50Hz the voltage that can be allowed is the same or higher (if rectified *1. 4 RMS), the idea is to use high voltage for hho electrolytic with lowest amperage.

Comment: You are not making any sense. I do not understand what you want.

Comment: I want to limit the current to 1 A

Comment: You already said that in your question. Your replies to my comment asking you questions made no sense to me and you only answered the first part. You are not getting anywhere so I will leave this to someone who is telepathic to make a great answer.

Comment: not funny i give you all information you need

Comment: @Andy aka I think he means something along the lines of current limiting using 'reactance' in his AC circuit.... As in using a resistor to limit current in a DC circuit? I think that's what he is getting at. I think he is trying to get an XL value close to the 225 mains voltage and wondering if this will work? I don't know for sure if that is what he is asking but it's what I got from it (my telepathic powers aren't great either)

Comment: @MCG exactly,because resistors consume a lot of energy so i want to do this with inductive reactance

Comment: Well in fairness to Andy, it was quite difficult to extract the information to actually get what you were trying to ask. As for answering, I do not actually know the answer, I haven't done it before and haven't looked into it so I cannot say whether it will or will not work. Hopefully someone will be able to answer now it is clarified what you are asking

Comment: @MCG I know what he wants but you or I or anyone can't answer it without answering the questions I raised earlier on. I'm not telepathic on what the load is or what minimum and maximum voltage it can tolerate. Vote to close question as being unclear.

Comment: @Andyaka that's a good point!

Comment: After your edit(s), it now seems a more appropriate question. However, you don't seem to have accounted for the voltage potential across your electrolysis unit. Now, if you're wanting to use the 800mH inductor as an "emergency limit" so if the electrolysis gets shorted only 1A flows, that'd work. Otherwise, you might find it limits the current more than you're wanting. -- ALSO, are you *sure* you want to use AC current for electrolysis? That's almost always a DC scenario, as AC will usually only cause corrosion, rather than predictable separation in electrolysis (or is it PEO you want)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the current to 1 amp with 225 V and 50 Hz applied to load of zero impedance (short circuit) then 225 / 1 = 225 ohm impedance. If 2πfL = 225 then L = .716 Henrys or 716 mH. If you don't know the load impedance, start with that and reduce it as required to achieve the current that you want.

Alternatively, use whatever assortment of incandescent light bulbs and heating appliances that you can find to determine what you need. Then get an appropriate inductor to reduce the wasted heat.

**You need to make the total of added impedance plus load impedance equal to 225 ohms when added vectorially. Z squared = X squared + R squared. The electrolysis process behaves like a resistor.**

The best but more costly approach would be to reduce the voltage with a transformer or a variable transformer or both.

Since you have asked the question without reference to why you want to produce HHO, I will restrain my self from saying what I think about that except to say be very careful!!

Answer (score 1):

here is an experiment of the impact of reactance on current i wish this help anyone asking the same question.

> "In AC circuits, inductors and capacitors behave in a similar way as resistors, limiting the flow of current in the circuit, this property is called reactance, and here we give a brief explanation and a demonstration."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWWXtesQL_w